# Promise chain with subtle asynchronous misordering

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

<del>A promise chain is useful for not over-writing a stream in node</del> (see Bergi's comment). But here's an example that in subtle asynch circumstances produces mis-ordered writes on the write stream:

```
var fs = require( 'fs' );

function WTest() {
  this.writeStream = fs.createWriteStream( 'junkTest.txt' );
  this.readyToWrite = Promise.resolve( true );
};

WTest.prototype.writeNext = function writeNext( text, callNum ) {
  this.readyToWrite = this.readyToWrite
    .then( status => writeToStream( text, this.writeStream, status, callNum ) );
}

var wTest = new WTest();

for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) wTest.writeNext( 
  `${i}, some line of text that might be xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx long \n`, i );

function writeToStream( text, writableStream, readyToWrite, callNum ) {
  return new Promise( ( resolve ) => {
    if ( readyToWrite ) resolve( writableStream.write( text ) );
    else writableStream.once( 'drain', () => resolve( writableStream.write( text ) ) );
  } );
}
```

If you run it as is in node 7.8, it works. But in complicated asynch circumstances, it fails, e.g. one line is written out of order. What's asynchronously dangerous about the above code? Can you create an asynch example where it fails?

My instance of failure includes multiple async file reads with the above code serving a logger function. I've verified that the calls to writeNext are arriving in the expected order by writing them to the console immediately after the call to the writeNext function. As mentioned in a comment, I've written with both (both direct to the same file), with the direct "just write" write (-) immediately after the promises write (=). The line sequence in the output file is 1-,1=,2-,3-,4-,5-,6-,7-,8-,2=,7=,3=,4=,5=,6=,9-,9=,10-,10=

Big picture wisdom from Bergi: "The only way to prevent over-writing is to stop generating new chunks." So the above is only of technical interest. Creating a promise chain worsens the memory cost of buffering.

Comment: "*A promise chain is useful for not over-writing a stream in node*" - Nope. You should just ignore the return value of `write` and keep writing. Sure, it'll fill the stream's buffer until the programs runs out of memory, but that's still much more efficient than buffering the data in a promise queue.

Comment: The only problem I see is that you might miss a `drain` event since you only start listening when there's another chunk to write instead of immediately after you got `false`, but that would lead to a forever-hanging stream and not to lines written out of order. Please post your actual code with the "*complicated asynch circumstances*", as probably that's where you are calling `writeNext` in an unexpected order.

Comment: @Bergi I'm sure I'm not writing in an unexpected order because if I stub out the call to writeNext with process.stdout.write, the output is produced in the correct order.

Comment: @Bergi [node 7.x docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_writable_write_chunk_encoding_callback) has serious warnings against just over-writing. Is that outdated or just wrong?

Comment: The warnings are neither outdated nor wrong. I'm just saying that your promise chain suffers from the exact same issue, and is even worse because the promises and closures will consume much more memory than the stream buffer. The only way to prevent over-writing is to *stop generating* new chunks - i.e. the `for` loop in your example.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "stub out". Are you doing *both* `stdout.write` and `writeNext`? Otherwise they're different runs and hardly comparable.

Comment: @Bergi I've written with both (both direct to the same file), with the direct "just write" write (-) immediately after the promises write (=). The line sequence in the output file is  1-,1=,2-,3-,4-,5-,6-,7-,8-,2=,7=,3=,4=,5=,6=,9-,9=,10-,10=

Comment: The only thing I can see that could go wrong is directing two streams into the same file.

Comment: @Bergi got the answer right for both big picture and specific technical question. Big picture: don't chain promises to avoid over-writing a stream. With respect to the specific technical question, Bergi's correct that's there's nothing wrong. Essentially I had two different WTest instances and was executing writes on different instances. That accounts for the different order. Would like to credit Bergi for correct answer, but don't see how to.

Comment: See, that's why I asked you to post your actual code :-)

Comment: I've posted an answer you can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The line sequence in the output file is
>   1-,1=,2-,3-,4-,5-,6-,7-,8-,2=,7=,3=,4=,5=,6=,9-,9=,10-,10=

The code from your question won't do that when there's only a single `WTest` instance and nothing else writes into that file.

> What's asynchronously dangerous about the above code? Can you create an asynch example where it fails?

The only problem I see is that you might miss a `drain` event since you only start listening when there's another chunk to write instead of immediately after you got `false`, but that would lead to a forever-hanging stream and not to lines written out of order.

Better:

```
function WTest(filename) {
  this.writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
  this.readyToWrite = Promise.resolve();
}
WTest.prototype.writeNext = function writeNext(text, callNum) {
  this.readyToWrite = this.readyToWrite.then(() => {
    const status = writeStream.write(text);
    if (!status)
      return new Promise(resolve => this.writeStream.once('drain', resolve));
  });
};
```